# Save log for session output

Tags: linux, bash, logging

How would I save my progress while reading a log file in `less`?

How should i use command `script` to save my command output to log.txt file?

### Scenario:

1. I open `logfile` with `less` and start reading page by page
2. When I'm done, I exit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
3. The rest of the unread `logfile` should be written to disk so I can open it later and pick up where I left off

[image]

In txt file I want save only when program start waiting for data (and if you click to page to save it to log) not all text before.

I've tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Write LOG file: " logfile

less +F $logfile >> log.txt
```

Comment: Are you looking for `tail`? Or are you trying to have interactive less logged to a file? What's the goal here exactly?

Comment: I am trying interactive (less) logged to a txt file.

Comment: but it's already in a log file: $logfile. This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- what are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I don't think you can get `less` to save the offset at which you quit, but that would make more sense to try to solve than what you are currently attempting.  Maybe [`less` bookmarks](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/07/less-command.html) could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer, but in less, this will append all the lines from start to the current screen to log.txt and quit:

```
|^cat >> log.txt
<return>
<return>
q
```